# API Call in Excel with Parameters passed through cells using Power Query

Tags: excel, api, powerquery

I am trying my hand at making an API call to a website using Power Query in Excel. Here are the steps I took to grab weather data from a website with an API key:

1. First, I launched Power Query editor so I can create parameters using Manage Parameters option. I created two parameters **pCity** and **pState**, gave each a value of *Philadelphia* and *PA*, respectively
2. I exited Power Query and back in Excel, under the **Data** tab, I clicked (Get Data) **From Web** ----> next, used the **Advanced** option where I set up the web address, specified parameters I was passing as per below screenshot:

[image]

I was able to load in the data just fine and that was great. However, I would like to be able to use cell B1 to hold the value of whatever City I wanted to pass to **pCity** parameter, and B2 to pass through the value of State to the **pState** parameter. I would then hit **Refresh All** and the table would update accordingly...and this is where I am stuck. How can I designate those cells as source of the values for the parameters. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are probably looking for a [Parameter Table](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/)

Comment: How would I translate that to a web query?